# HTML - Can I wrap a series of <div> tags inside a parent <div>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, word-wrap

I've been trying this for a while with no luck. I have a parent `<div>` tag (lets say it's set to `300px` in width). I am trying to add a series of smaller `<div>` tags to go inside the parent, and be placed side by side until the edge of the parent `<div>` where the next child `<div>` will then be placed on the "next line". Basically, I am trying to make these child `<div>` tags act like words being word wrapped.

I have googled this like crazy, but I can't find any way to really do this without calculating the sizing of everything and manually placing the child `<div>`'s with absolute coordinates, which I can do, but I'd like to avoid. Sp first, I was wondering if there was a `css` or `javascript` approach that could supply the same behavior.

The number of child divs is variable, and I am using C# server side code to calculate them. But it shouldn't matter which server language I'm using.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

### Approach 1

Use `display: inline-block;`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#parent {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/NdWUz/)

```
<hr>
<h2>Approach 2</h2>
```

Use `float: left;`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
    <div id="child"></div>
    <div id="child"></div>
    <div id="child"></div>
    <div id="child"></div>
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#parent {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
#child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/NdWUz/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Floating is a totally reasonable way to do it.

Alternatively you could use elements with CSS display:inline or display:inline-block . Both are automatically positioned by the browser as you describe, side-by-side and "wrapping" when they run out of space. The difference is that inline elements don't give you as much control over padding, dimensions etc., whereas inline-block elements give you all the perks of a display:block element. However IE6 does have some difficulty with inline-block elements, as I recall, which is irritating.

If you want to use inline elements, just switch your child divs to spans: spans are inline by default, no further work necessary. However there are no elements that display inline-block by default, so if you need to use this you may as well keep your divs.

Hopefully you have some options there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just float: left the child divs?